# Apaache Web Server On google compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

I am getting this error when I try to connect to SSH

> Connection Failed
>   An error occurred while communicating with the SSH server.
>   Check the server and the network configuration.

When I checked under serial port 1 I see the following

> Permissions 0644 for '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed2678_key' are too open.

How can I change the permission since I can not access SSH server

Comment: `chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed2678_key`

Comment: Thanks. But I can't open SSH server. Where should I type this?

Comment: you should be able to connect to the console, didn't use GC but a friend of mine was, so I remember that the console access was one of the features he missed on another platform

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console

Comment: As 'Dan' explained you can connect to the machine via serial console to debug. Also you can follow this steps in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh) to troubleshoot.